# MongoDB find function with a date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604ddfa77971df6a5fefa6a7"),
    "Date" : "03/07/2017",
    "Region_code" : "",
    "Org_code" : "",
    "Org_Name" : "",
    "Contract_code" : "111AD8",
    "Contract_name" : "East London and City 111AD8",
    "5_3" : 418
}
```

This is the kind of document that I have.
I need to limit my `find()` function to a single month (eg: only Jan 2020)
So i tried with the $regex function(the plan is to basically use the "like" command like in `SQL`):

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.calls2020.find({"Date":{$regex:/01/01/2020/m}}).pretty()
```

or

```
db.calls2020.find({Date: /"01/01/2020"/m}).pretty()
```

But it keeps giving me the following error:

```
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing } after property list :
@(shell):1:38
```

I believe that since the field that I'm searching already has a "/" symbol it's creating an issue here. How can I work around that? I already tried putting the date between brackets `()`,`{}`; but still doesn't work.

Thank you for your help.

p.s. 
I'm an absolute beginner with any type of database management system or coding in general so please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Why do you save date as a plain text? You should better consider to change data type of that field. It's not handy to write regex for all this kind of operations. Also, you may need to consider timezone etc... Time is important :) good luck

Comment: You should **never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` object.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit This is how the dataset was. Was there anything I could have done to change the way a field is stored when you import a dataset?

Comment: How do you import the data into your MongoDB?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I keep the csv file in my bin folder, then I run:
"mongoimport -d dbname -c colname -- type format --file filename.format --headerline"

Comment: Try to define date format with [--columnsHaveTypes](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/#std-option-mongoimport.--columnsHaveTypes) option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/` is a special character for the regex. You should escape special characters.
In your case, to find records from Jan 2020 -> `/[0-9]{2}\/01\/2020/`

Example dataset

```js
MongoDB Enterprise rs0:PRIMARY> db.test.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("604ddfa77971df6a5fefa6a7"),
        "Date" : "03/07/2017",
        "Region_code" : "",
        "Org_code" : "",
        "Org_Name" : "",
        "Contract_code" : "111AD8",
        "Contract_name" : "East London and City 111AD8",
        "5_3" : 418
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("304ddfa77971df6a5fefa6a7"),
        "Date" : "01/01/2020",
        "Region_code" : "",
        "Org_code" : "",
        "Org_Name" : "",
        "Contract_code" : "111AD8",
        "Contract_name" : "East London and City 111AD8",
        "5_3" : 418
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("804ddfa77971df6a5fefa6a7"),
        "Date" : "02/01/2020",
        "Region_code" : "",
        "Org_code" : "",
        "Org_Name" : "",
        "Contract_code" : "111AD8",
        "Contract_name" : "East London and City 111AD8",
        "5_3" : 418
}
```

Selecting Jan 2020 by regex

```js
MongoDB Enterprise rs0:PRIMARY> db.test.find({"Date": { $regex: /[0-9]{2}\/01\/2020/}}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("304ddfa77971df6a5fefa6a7"),
        "Date" : "01/01/2020",
        "Region_code" : "",
        "Org_code" : "",
        "Org_Name" : "",
        "Contract_code" : "111AD8",
        "Contract_name" : "East London and City 111AD8",
        "5_3" : 418
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("804ddfa77971df6a5fefa6a7"),
        "Date" : "02/01/2020",
        "Region_code" : "",
        "Org_code" : "",
        "Org_Name" : "",
        "Contract_code" : "111AD8",
        "Contract_name" : "East London and City 111AD8",
        "5_3" : 418
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 "Date" : "03/07/2017",
"Region_code" : "",
"Org_code" : "", 
"Org_Name" : "",
"Contract_code" : "111AD8",
"Contract_name" : "East London and City 111AD8",
"5_3" : 418
}
```

- For such a record with Date `"Date" : "03/07/2017",` targeting `month and year`
- Command
  db.getCollection('Your collection').find({ "Date" : { $regex: /07/2017/}})
- Read more on Regex on mongodb official Doc https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/
- In future you may consider using time stamps also
  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/

Answer (score 0):

Using string for date values is usually a bad design. I would suggest solution like this:

```
db.calls2020.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         date_parts: {
            $dateToParts: {
               date: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$Date", format: "%d/%m/%Y" } }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $match: { "date_parts.year": 2017, "date_parts.month": 7 } }
])
```